# Having trouble setting up JavaFX on NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I need to setup JavaFX for the NetBeans IDE but I seem to be getting errors. I'm running the latest version of JDK 12. Here's what's happening:
[image]

This is what I got from the automatic setup. So I looked up tutorials on the internet and noticed that I have to enable it through the JavaFX tab but it seems to be missing as seen here:

[image]

As you can see, I tried setting up a new platform and included the .JRE files from the lib folder of the JavaFX folder but it hasn't helped. How do I set this up correctly?

Comment: Go to [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/). Read the `JavaFX and Netbeans` part.

Comment: I hope someone may explain more, but OpenJFX is what is needed. I would switch to a _maven_ project to gather all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I chose Java with Ant (Java Application), not a JavaFX project. Then I downloaded the JavaFX 12 and added the libraries. You must edit not only the library tab, but also the run tab.
Check the video "Setup JavaFX 11 or 12 on Netbeans 11 with JDK12" - Bert Bronson video on youtube.